# Why is this method of forward declaration producing an error?

Tags: c++, class

```
// practice.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"

using namespace std;

class one;
int main()
{
    one alpha;
    cin.get();
}

class one
{

};
```

I have no idea why the above method is producing an error: object uses undefined class. Any help would be nice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Forward-declaring allows you to create a pointer or reference to a class. However, in order to use the class, which includes creating an instance of it, the full class definition is required by the compiler at that point.

Comment: Would you be able to tell me how creating the pointer / reference works in this case? I would appreciate any help.

Comment: @shadoweye14 `one* alpha` and `one& alpha = ...` respectively. They can be used without the class definition because the pointer/reference variable just stores a *memory address*, not the actual object.

Comment: @shadoweye14: Creating a `T*` does not require knowing how big a `T` is, or what's inside it. Creating a `T` does.

Comment: Ahh I see. Learnt something new today. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define class before you use it. forward declaration works only for pointers, but that is not the way you are using.

Comment: That's a little simplistic. There are a few scenarios in which forward declaration is sufficient. You're right, though, in that this is not one of them.

Answer (score 0):

Compiler need to know the full definition of the class before you define an object,if you want to define the class lately, you can define a pointer or reference first, and initlize it after you define the class